# How to send additional parameter with cancel subscription?

Tags: laravel, laravel-cashier

I want to cancel a subscription using laravel cashier and send some additional info with cancel.
My code is-

```
   $user->subscription('main')->noProrate()->cancel(['param1'=>'value1']);
```

But it is not working.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can use your own params in as in the arguments array. According to the stripe API there are 2 possible arguments https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel
Could you try those and report back if it's working?

Comment: Yes , `['param1'=>'value1']` is the argument array but i'm unable to send with cancel request

Comment: @Rik, Got it sir , Thank you very much

Comment: I don't think `cancel()` accepts arguments though. You might need to override the cancel method.